# Registering an application to start on logon in a Debain package

Tags: shell, debian, packaging, deb, software-packaging

I'm bundling my Java application as Debian package and I need my application to run at start up. Here's my DEB package structure:

```
   +
   |
   +--+control
   |  |
   |  +--+control
   |  |
   |  +--+md5sums
   |  |
   |  +--+postinst
   |  |
   |  +--+prerm
   |
   +--+data
      |
      +--+usr
         |
         +--+share
            |
            +--+applications
            |  |
            |  +--+MyApp.desktop
            |
            +--+myapp
               |
               +--+bin
               |  |
               |  +--+application.sh
               |
               +--+application.jar
```

My Jar file is executed using the script `application.sh`. My installation script `postinst` contains only:

```
#!/bin/sh
ln -s /usr/share/myapp/bin/application.sh /usr/bin/myapp
```

I'd like to execute the `myapp` script when the user logs on the machine. What would I have to add to this script so that the application gets run automatically.

Thanks.

(This is my first time builing DEB packages and what i've learnt so far has been by digging through some projects on SourceForce but I'm still a little lost with the start-on-startup feature.)

Comment: At startup, at login, or at graphical login?

Comment: At a graphical login. This is a system tray application.

Answer (score 1):

[Desktop Application Autostart Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)

> By placing an application's .desktop file in one of the Autostart directories the application will be automatically launched during startup of the user's desktop environment after the user has logged in.

Comment: So a `.desktop` file is a like a Windows shortcut file it seems. Does that mean that would need to copy the `.desktop` file to the `applications` directory and also to the `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`. Copying it to the `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` would cause it to autostart and coping to the `applications` directory would cause it to appear in the menus. Am I correct Ignacio? Thanks.

Comment: Correct. But they don't necessarily have to be the same.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again Ignacio but in `postrm` script do I need to remove both the `.desktop` files or are they removed automatically somehow? (This could be a separate question but it felt do trivial.) Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know anything about how .deb files work. I'd think that they'd just be part of the package payload, so you wouldn't need to do anything either way.